# Transparent webview in monodroid, android 4.0+

Tags: android, webview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to make my webview transparent.

Right now my webview looks like this in xml:

I have set the background to transparent, but it doesn't work. Then I found this post, tried it, but doesn't work either: [Monodroid Transparent WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646883/monodroid-transparent-webview)

My webview just turned black.

I'm testing on my Nexus 5 with Android 4.4.4, and the WebView background is still black setting color:

```
mWeb.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);
```

OR

```
mWeb.SetBackgroundColor(new Color(0x00000000));
```

OR

```
mWeb.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent); 
mWeb.SetBackgroundDrawable(null); 
mWeb.SetBackgroundResource(0);
```

But if I test it on a device with android 2.3, it works! So what to do on devices running 4.0+?

My HTML-code look like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <style>
            h1
            {
                font-weight:700;
            }
            html
            {
                background-color:transparent;
            }

            ul
            {
                padding:0 20px;
            }

            li
            {
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
            }

            div
            {
                background-color:transparent;
            }
            table
            {
               border-collapse:collapse;
            } 
            table td
            {
               border:none;
               outline:none;
            }
            body
            {
                background-color:transparent;
                margin:0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        // MY TEXT GOES HERE!
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answer you posted i am also using the following code to set my webview to transparent:

```
wview.SetBackgroundColor(new Color(0,0,0,0));
```

It should work on devices running 4.0+. But be sure that what you show in the webview is also set to use a transparent background. - That is the body of you html and whatever js or jquery libraries you are using.

Comment: Hi Christian. Thanks for your replay. I have updated my question with my HTML code. The html shoud be transparent.